# How to override msbuild variable with the empty value on the command line?

Tags: msbuild

Please, observe the following trivial msbuild script named `1.targets`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="PrintInfo">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <x Condition="'$(x)' == ''">hello</x>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="PrintInfo">
    <Message Text="x = $(x)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Now I am testing it:

```
C:\temp> msbuild .\1.targets /v:m /nologo
  x = hello
C:\temp> msbuild .\1.targets /v:m /nologo /p:x=bye
  x = bye
C:\temp> msbuild .\1.targets /v:m /nologo /p:x=""
  x =
C:\temp> msbuild .\1.targets /v:m /nologo /p:x=
  x =
C:\temp>
```

Why passing the empty value does not satisfy the condition `'$(x)' == ''` and does not print `hello`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make [global properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties#global-properties) mutable by adding `TreatAsLocalProperty="x"` to your root node.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" TreatAsLocalProperty="x"> 
</Project>
```

> msbuild C:\Go.build /v:m /nologo /p:x=

Will produce

> x = hello

Answer (score 3):

When a property is specified on the command line, it is a [global property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties#global-properties):

> MSBuild lets you set properties on the command line by using the
>   /property (or /p) switch. These global property values override
>   property values that are set in the project file. This includes
>   environment properties, but does not include reserved properties,
>   which cannot be changed.

If you need to set the value to a default, you need to change it inside of the target since the global property will overwrite the "static" (outside of a target) declaration.

```
<Target Name="PrintInfo">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <x Condition="'$(x)' == ''">hello</x>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="x = $(x)" Importance="High" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I still do not understand why my original code does not work.

Comment: Global properties overwrite the definition in the project file, so any `<x>` in the main body of the project is a no-op.

Comment: I am sorry, still do not get it. I have `x` in the project file and I override it on the command line. The override works just fine - if I pass `bye` it displays `bye` instead of the project defined `hello`. But it works too good. If I pass the empty value it override `hello` as well, despite the condition which should leave it alone when the value is empty.

Comment: Yes the "empty value" is still what will be used, you will overwrite any `<x>` definition in the static part of the project with the empty value in this case. Use different names for the variables you want to pass (`xOverride`) or move the logic to targets.